# Why is the "Scan/Choose/Connect" model universally used by most OSes for Wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iphone

I [posed a question yesterday on the Unix-Linux board](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705949/why-is-connection-to-iphone-personal-wifi-hotspot-so-flaky-with-ubuntu-linux) about how I might have a less unstable way of connecting a Linux laptop to my Personal IPhone Hotspot. It hasn't really received a true answer, other than [my own workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706040/106105).

But here, I would like to pose the question on a more theoretical level. All Operating Systems I am familiar with, principally many flavors of Linux, as well as Windows, use what I call the *"Scan/Choose/Connect"* model to establish WiFi connections. The User Interface of all these systems has some way of bringing to the screen a list of available Wifi Networks (compiled from a scanning process), from which the user is invited to choose, then prompting for a credential (password), which if validated, allows and makes the connection. This is undoubtedly an ideal sweet-spot for the vast majority of user-interactions for wifi-connection.

But, consider the IPhone Personal Hotspot use case. A user owns both an IPhone and a laptop computer running some OS, let's say Linux, but it could just as well be Windows. The user on a fairly frequent basis needs to use their IPhone as internet provider for their laptop in an environment where no wifi is available.

In this use case, the user owns both pieces of equipment. They know the ID and password of their IPhone hotspot. It should be possible to write some sort of shell script (or batch file in Windows) supplying both of these data items and telling their system to switch its network from whatever it's trying to point to (and failing if there's no wifi) to the IPhone, which the user knows is nearby and operating. Scanning should not be necessary in this scenario, and makes the whole process more frustrating. In my scenario, the connection attempt will either succeed or fail and report accordingly.

I have searched around the Internet for a generally accepted answer to this use case, and have not found anything authoritative. **And I wonder why not**.  Can someone explain for me why this is generally not published, or point me at a place where it is answered?

A related question is this: if an IPhone hotspot does not appear in the scan list of the computer trying to connect to it, would any such script be guaranteed to fail if tried?

Comment: Simply because "scan-choose-connect" is the easiest for most people to understand, and covers the vast majority of use cases.  But most OSes remember previous WiFi networks, so the PC will connect to the nearby iPhone if it's available.

Comment: I understand, and mentioned in my original post that the Scan/Choose/Connect is optimum for most use cases. But I've found your scenario of remembering past connections not to be always the case. Frequently the IPhone does NOT appear on the list of available networks. Sometimes, it does appear after a long wait. Sometimes it doesn't appear at all. My workaround is to turn the hotspot off and back on on the phone. This sometimes helps. But much easier would be a script that just tried to make the connection without scanning, unless there is some reason why it won't work, that I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but still involves scanning as the computer must find out *which frequency* the network is available on.

For example, NetworkManager saves each Wi-Fi network as a "connection profile" that you can activate at any time,  e.g. using `nmcli con up <name>`. But whenever you do so, it still needs to search all channels for any access points providing that SSID – of which there could be multiple, and/or they could have different capabilities from last time. (Your hotspot always finds a new channel every time you enable it, so that's not something the computer *could* remember.)

It *might* still achieve your goal of connecting faster, however, as NetworkManager will disconnect from the old network first before looking for the new one. Normally, when you're actively using a network on one specific channel, the Wi-Fi adapter can't be too aggressive about scanning for networks on other channels, as it cannot send/receive data during that time (see e.g. various posts by gamers asking how to disable background scans as they cause unexpected latency) – and there's a lot of channels it needs to check, one at a time. This is at least part of why available networks may be slow to appear in the list. (That being said, opening the network list in current versions of GNOME does trigger an immediate scan – but the 'nmcli' equivalent doesn't.)

Comment: Good explanation, thanks